# Xcode: Delete files but still tracked by git

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git

I delete files from my project that I no longer want. But when I want to commit, git keeps tracking them as "new file: project / myFile.swift"

How can I do to delete files permanently in Xcode? so they don't show up in git when I want to commit ?

is it possible to fix this without using git ignore?

Comment: Did you delete the files with `rm the-file` or with `git rm the-file`, or did you use something else? If you used `git rm the-file` you should be fine; if you didn't, make sure you type `git rm the-file` at the console to remove both the working tree copy and the to-be-committed repository copy. Note that existing commits will be unaffected: if they already have the file, they will continue to have it; if they already omit the file, they will continue to omit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delete files from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YWKV.png)

Instead of clicking *Remove Reference*, click *Move to Trash*.
Removing the reference only removes the file from Xcode project but it does not remove it from the project directory.